# Remote Access over the Network to a Virtual Box Machine

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, remote-desktop

I am trying to remotely access a machine on Virtual Box, which is on a terminal server, but I don't want to have to log onto the terminal server first.

I have enabled the Remote Display Settings in Virtual Box Manager.

[image: Virtual Box Remote Display Settings]

The firewall on the Virtual Machine is not blocking access, as I can ping the machine from my local machine, and from the terminal server.

The issue is when I try to RDP into the machine, it asks me for the username and password, which I give the correct information, but says it fails to connect.

Is this just my issue, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to log in using the computer's IP address, then I was using a UK keyboard and typing the wrong password in. The keyboard on the machine is a US keyboard, so the password is totally different. Like the `@` symbol is on the right side of the keyboard, etc.

Thank you for looking at the question and trying to help me sort it out.

Comment: The obvious "way" to check would be checking the default keyboard/locale settings of the system running in the VM.
Looks likes this is using default US...

Comment: @AndréSchild yes it is. I didn't realise it before, so my colleague tried it and worked first time, then he told me what he did. :)

Answer (score 1):

I assume that your virtualbox has not a own IP address, but rather some nat or host-only network.

So when you RDP to your TSE, it's the TSE login you see.

I would do the following:

- Make the VM use a bridged network and assign it it's own IP address
- In Virtualbox don't enable remote display
- In the guest OS, activate the RDP access

This way you can directly authenticate against the guest OS